# Django 1.3 formsets not respecting error_class specification?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have several formsets to which I am passing `error_class`es, but the formset is just not using the specified class to render errors.

The error_class works for standalone forms (such as `form` in the below snippet).

I'm using Django 1.3. Is there a way to get formsets to do this?

My view code:

```
    form = IncorporateForm(request.POST, error_class=SideError)
    guarantee_form = GuaranteeForm(data=request.POST, error_class=SideError)
    directors_formset = DirectorsFormset(prefix='directors', data=request.POST, error_class=SideError\
)
    capital_formset = CapitalFormset(prefix='capital', data=request.POST, error_class=SideError)
    holding_formset = HoldingFormset(prefix='holding', data=request.POST, error_class=SideError)
    amends_formset = AmendsFormset(prefix='amends', data=request.POST, error_class=SideError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that Formset does not pass down the error_class to the forms it creates.

I've created this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16479
That ticket details the fix, which is to change the first line in Formset._construct_form to:

```
defaults = {'auto_id': self.auto_id, 'prefix': self.add_prefix(i), 'error_class': self.error_class}
```

That passes the error_class to each form created.